# How to add target to Camera Capture Session after it's started?

Tags: android, android-camera2, video-recording

I'm attempting to add a new target to my camera2 capture session after the capture session has already been created and configured.

My goal is to be able to have a smooth recording using a media codec with the ability to toggle a preview on and off (without toggling the texture view as visible/invisible).

Currently, I have been able to add or remove targets by switching between/creating different capture sessions, however, this results in small freezes in the recordings when I open/close the preview activity/capture sessions, which I need to eliminate.

After scouring the internet I haven't found any other way to add targets other than creating a new capture session, which the capture session documentation itself says is "expensive" and can take "several hundred milliseconds".

> Creating a session is an expensive operation and can take several hundred milliseconds, since it requires configuring the camera device's internal pipelines and allocating memory buffers for sending images to the desired targets.<

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession

Is this the only way? Or am I just missing something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't just leave the preview output Surface in the capture session, but not include the preview target in the capture requests when you're not using it?

You can change the set of outputs you're actually sending images to, for every output frame, so it's very flexible and fast.

Comment: I have not discovered a way to create a preview output surface that is not tied to an already created view of some sort. The entire time my app is running it is recording, but there are certain points I want to toggle on a preview. So I don't start the camera with a created texture view. Whenever I've tried to add a preview without tying it to a a specific initialized view from an activity I get a null object reference. I'm sure there's a way to add a preview surface without having a created texture view in an activity, but I honestly am not sure how without having the context or view.

Comment: You can create a SurfaceTexture object at any point, and then link it to a TextureView once you have one.

Comment: I created a SurfaceTexture object using: 

`SurfaceTexture otherTexture = new SurfaceTexture(10);` 

then send it to my Preview class and set the TextureView equal to it, however, although the received surface texture is not null the TextureView won't display anything to the screen. Is there an additional step I'm missing? I chose 10 arbitrarily, does it need to be a specific number?